# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory Python

Tags: python, file, file-io, io

I have this piece of code, trying to find `*.vm` files, and send them to another

module i did, which supposed to read the lines.

this is the main file:

```
def VMTranslte(fileName):
print "FILEOVER ",fileName
from parser import Parser
from codeWriter import CodeWriter
if (fileName[-3:] == ".vm"):
    outputFile = fileName[:-3]+".asm"
    myWrite = CodeWriter(outputFile)
    myWrite.setFileName(fileName)
    myParser = Parser(fileName)
    myWrite.setFileName(fileName);
    translate(myParser,myWrite)
else:
    if fileName[-1:] == "/": <===== CHECKS FOR DIRECTORY
        mystr = fileName.split('/')[-2]
        mystr = mystr.split('.')[0]+".asm"
        outputFile = fileName+mystr
    else:
        outputFile = fileName+".asm"
    myWrite = CodeWriter(outputFile)
    for child in os.listdir(fileName):
        if child.endswith('.vm'): <===== CHECK IF THERE IS *.vm FILE
            print "CHILD: ",child <===== PRINTS THE FILE WANTED (MEANING FINDS IT)
            myWrite.setFileName(child);
            myParser = Parser(child) <===== CALLS THE READER MODULE DESCRIBED AT THE BOTTOM
            translate(myParser,myWrite) 
myWrite.close()
```

the module which supposed to read the lines:

```
#Constructor for Parser module.
def __init__(self,fileName):
    import re
    self.cmds = []
    self.counter = 0
    myFile = open(fileName, 'r') <=====ERROR OVER HERE
    fLines = myFile.readlines()
    for value in fLines : 
        lineStrip = value.strip()
        if not (re.match("//",lineStrip) or len(lineStrip)==0):
            self.cmds.append(lineStrip)
```

the error is:

```
  File "/Users/***/Desktop/dProj7/parser.py", line 19, in __init__
  myFile = open(fileName, 'r')
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'BasicTest.vm'
```

it is clear that the script finds the file, (he goes in the first loop),

what is going on over here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

os.listdir does not include the path, only the name of the file.  You probably want to call Parser with `os.path.join(fileName, child)` as the argument.